# problem with python and telebot in persian language for sending message

Tags: python, utf-8, farsi, telebot

A text in Persian language is stored in a txt file.

I want to send its contents using Python and Telebot in Telegram, but the letters are messed up in Telegram.

The file storage format is UTF-8.
I changed the content to string before posting.

But the message in Telegram is still messed up. How do I solve this problem?

CODE:

```py
import telebot

bot_token = "MY_TOKEN"
file_path = "C:/shr.txt"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
def send_file_content(message):
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    text_str = str(content)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text_str)
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def start_command(message):
send_file_content(message)
bot.polling()
```

result in Telegram:

```
20%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%98%C2%B6%C3%99%E2%80%9A%20%C3%99%CB%86%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%B2%C3%9B%C5%92%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%E2%80%A0%0A%0Ai%20love%20you%0A%0A
```

Comment: Show code and the error message or symptom of the problem.

Comment: I added the codes to the first post

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `from urllib.parse import unquote; unquote( '20%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%98%C2%B6%C3%99%E2%80%9A%20%C3%99%CB%86%C3%98%C2%B1%C3%98%C2%B2%C3%9B%C5%92%C3%98%C2%AF%C3%99%E2%80%A0%0A%0Ai%20love%20you%0A%0A','utf-8').encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'20عضق ورزیدن\n\ni love you\n\n'`…

Comment: Please ensure your code example is indented correctly and reproduces the problem.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: It appears you are on Windows.  Use `open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8')`.  The default encoding on Windows is a encoding based on the localized version of Windows used.  It appears to be Windows-1252 (US or Western European version) based on JosefZ's comment.

Comment: Please feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you resolved the issue.